# N numbers are being drafted without returning. What is the probability that the ones drawn before ith number are smaller than ith.

Tags: probability

There are N different numbers on N cards. The cards are being drawn without returning. What is the probability that the number on $i$th drawn card is bigger than all the previous ones and show that for each $i$ events are idependent.

What i got so far:

The results are $n$-element permutations.

Let $A_i$ be the event that $i$th drawn number is bigger than all previous ones.

Let $B_m$ be the event that in $i$th draw number $m$ was drawn.

Then we have:

$ \Bbb{P}(A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n \Bbb{P}(A_i|B_m)\Bbb{P}(B_m)$

$\Bbb{P}(B_m) = \frac{1}{n}$

if $ m < i \quad $ then $A_i \cap B_m$ is impossible

Then I'm getting stuck.

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry, each of the first $i$ numbers has the same probability of being the greatest among them. Thus the probability for the $i$-th number to be greater than all previous ones is $\frac1i$.

It's not clear to me what you mean by “for each $i$ the events are independent”. The events $A_i$ are mutually independent since permuting the first $i-1$ elements doesn't change the probability of the $i$-th element to be greater than they.